# No aparece el menu de Hibernate en Netbeans 12.4

Tags: netbeans, hibernate, java-ee

Buen día Red.

Estoy intentando crear un proyecto en Netbeans 12.4 pero me encontré con un problema.
Resulta que tengo un proyecto Maven y estoy intentando configurar Hibernate, pero no me sale el menú para crear el hibernate.cfg.xml.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya agregue hibernate a las dependencias del proyecto y e intentado de todo pero nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien mas le ha pasado y lo ha solucionado?

Ojala puedan ayudarme.
Saludos!!

Comment: No suelo usar Netbeans sino Eclipse pero ahí estoy viendo el tipo de fichero XML y tú quieres crear hibernate.cfg.xml ...

Comment: Si es cierto... Pero según lo que he leído en internet... Debe salir un menú especial para hibernate dónde se crean los mapeos y archivos de configuración... Por eso me entró la duda.

Comment: Has probado en la carpeta Persistence?

Comment: Si... Pero son los archivos para usar jpa... No hibernate

Comment: Busca en la pagina de extensiones de netbeans, debe haber uno para hibernate, llevan la extensión .nbm

Comment: En efecto, el problema es que al intentar instalar el plugin, me sale que falta el Freemarker y no lo encuentro por ningún lado. "The plugin Freemarker Integration is requested in implementation version 238."

Comment: si siguiendo este tutorial https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html no funciona levanta un ticket